# Codeigniter 2.0 how to insert records in two tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have these two `tables('users','users2')` I want to insert data in my two tables. What would be the best approach? using array?

My Model code is :

```
function user_add($option){
      $this->db->set('userid',$option['user_id']);
      $this->db->set('email', $option['email']);
      $this->db->set('password', $option['pw']);
      $this->db->set('created', 'NOW()', false);
      $this->db->insert('users');
      //users2 tables
      $this->db->set('user_id',$option['user_id']);
      $this->db->insert('users2');
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that, or via array

```
$array = array(
    'userid' => $option['user_id'],
    'email' => $option['email'],
    'password' => $option['password'],
    'created' => time(),
);

$this->db->set($array);
$this->db->insert('users');

$this->db->set($array);
$this->db->insert('users2');
```

Using the array, you can reuse the variable as much as you want, including array manipulations to remove or add keys.

Answer (score 1):

Create ***2 functions in controller***.

1. for insert table 01
2. for insert table 02

> **It is not good practice to use two methods in one model function**

**In Controller**

```
public function method_name
{
    $this->Model_name->user_add_table1($option);
    $this->Model_name->user_add_table2($option);
}
```

**In Model**

```
function user_add_table1($option){
    $this->db->set('userid',$option['user_id']);
    $this->db->set('email', $option['email']);
    $this->db->set('password', $option['pw']);
    $this->db->set('created', 'NOW()', false);
    $this->db->insert('users');
}
function user_add_table2($option){
    $this->db->set('userid',$option['user_id']);
    $this->db->set('email', $option['email']);
    $this->db->set('password', $option['pw']);
    $this->db->set('created', 'NOW()', false);
    $this->db->insert('users');
}
```

Comment: why you remove the accepting is there any problem in this??